# Finding duplicates in 2D array - Row and Column

Tags: c

I would like to know how do I find duplicates separately - Row and Column.

So far I think I have this for the row, haven't really tested it out. But I am kinda confuse how to find duplicates for a 2D array in column fashion? I need to implement 2 functions one to find duplicate for row and the other one to find duplicate for column.

```
bool uniqueRow(int square[][MAX_SIZE], int sqrSize, int i) {

   int j;

   for(i = 0; i < sqrSize; ++i) {
      for(j = i; i < sqrSize && square[i][i] != square[i][j]; ++j) {

         if(square[i][i] == square[i][j])
            return false;

         else
            return true;
      }
   }

   return false;
}
bool uniqueCol(int square[][MAX_SIZE], int sqrSize, int i) {

   int j;

   for(i = 0; i < sqrSize; ++i) {
      for(j = i; i < sqrSize && square[i][i] != square[j][i]; ++j) {

         if(square[i][i] == square[j][i])
            return false;

         else 
            return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a loop example that would work:

```
int i, j, rowLenght = 6, colLenght = 6, arr[rowLenght][colLenght];
for(i = 0; i < rowLenght; ++i) {
   for(j = i; i < colLenght && arr[i][i] != arr[i][j]; ++j);

   if(arr[i][i] == arr[i][j])
     printf("We have mathch at arr[%d][%d] is same as arr[%d][%d]", i, i, i, j);
}
```

and simply you swap around few variables and you got column matching one

```
int i, j, rowLenght = 6, colLenght = 6, arr[rowLenght][colLenght];
for(i = 0; i < rowLenght; ++i) {
  for(j = i; i < colLenght && arr[i][i] != arr[j][i]; ++j);

  if(arr[i][i] == arr[j][i])
    printf("We have mathch at arr[%d][%d] is same as arr[%d][%d]", i, i, j, i);
}
```

Comment: is the ; after the second for loop intended? or should it be another {}?

Comment: it is intended `for(;;);` is same as `for(;;){}`

Comment: That's strange then cause it doesn't seems to work. I edited a little to fit in my functions. Can you help me take a look at my edited code above? I need to return false if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about the efficiency (your code is already in O(n^2)), use a `HashSet` to add elements to it using the `add(elem)` method, and look for duplicates for every single element in the 2D matrix using the `contains(elem)` method.

You add an element to the HashSet if it doesn't already contain it - no duplicates can be stored.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, I am quite a newbie, so it would be good to stick with just plain old looping if possible. Actually, for the first function, I just wanted to make sure for the 2D array, each row has unique values. Similarly, I also want to search in column fashion to make sure it is unique and if so, output true.

Comment: Well, I forgot to metion that its in java... You could use stl vector in C++, and make use of the find() method

Comment: Hmm...I am dealing with C only.

Comment: Wait... Looping, huh? Then I've got an idea. Simply create an array(a temporary one), and scan it to check if the element of the 2D matrix exists. If not, add it to the temp array. If yes, you found a duplicate.

Comment: Hmm...Is my above code workable for looking for duplicates for row?

Comment: Whoa, I just re read your code. Its an O(n^4) algorithm, and most of it isn't what you want. I'll instead post a code snippet for you in the answer below.

Comment: Actually I am thinking do I even need 4 for loops since I am just checking for row. Would 2 do the job?

Comment: @kenny, look at my other answer. I used 3 loops. It is still inefficient, but better than having 4 loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here, take this code instead:

```js
//Assuming int a[][] contains all input elements,
//and that n is the number of rows and columns

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    int tmp[n], size=0, dup=0;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
      if(size>0)
        {
          int k=0;
          while(k<size)
            {
              //comparing each element of tmp with current row's(i) current(j) element
              if(a[j]==tmp[k])
                {
                  dup=1;
                  break;
                }
              else
                k++;
            }
          if(k==size&&k<n){ //updated here,
            tmp[k]=a[j];    //
            size++;         //and here, incrementing size
            }
        }
      if(dup==1)
        printf("Duplicate found");
    }
  }
```

This will compare each element of the row to a temporary array of element containing unique elements of the row. You can take a similar approach for columns.

Comment: May I know what is the purpose of the size?

Comment: Here, "size" is the integer variable which stores the size of the array "tmp". Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to increment the value of size. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @kenny , Size of "tmp" increases as unique elements are found in the array. We know that the maximum size of "tmp" could be "n", as it is the maximum number of elements in a row.

Comment: And, @kenny , the answer posted by GRC is logically flawed. It wouldn't work. He is checking diagonals' elements with every other element, so duplicates will only be found if they are in the diagonal of the 2D array, else it'll just slip off. And, don't forget to mark this as your answer.